# Font-awesome unicode not working for version 5.11.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, font-awesome

I have the following code and from it, I'd really like to help me with the following:

Why are the icons not showing up (it only shows a square)? I used the same code with Font Awesome 4.7.0 and it works fine. However, it does not for this version (5.11.2).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;

  &:before {
    content: '\f085'; // fas fa-cogs
        font-family: fontAwesome;
  }
}

.toggle.active {
  background-color: red;

  &:before {
    content: '\f00d'; //fas fa-times
  } 
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.active{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to my CodePen in case you find it easier:
https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/yLLgBRq

P.S.: I am using SCSS as a CSS preprocessor and the CSS link to font-awesome is included in my CodePen.

Comment: @Paulie_D the code comes from my CodePen. I included the link there.

Comment: check the duplicate if you want to understand the font-weight trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.toggle::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f007";
}
```

Use double colons for using before.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: I tried this in the past but without the font-weight. I noticed that by adding the font-weight it does work. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; Font awesome provides this library for pseudo-elements. This font family is available for free. Check the link I had shared in the post. That link contains all details.

Comment: Plz accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: it has partially worked as it has two parts

Comment: what your other question that has not worked?

Comment: I want to use font-awesome classes and not unicode, that is what I've used, but I don't know how to use classes for toggles

Comment: No, You cant add HTML or classes in content in CSS stylesheet.

Comment: I am aware of that. I'll try to post a clearer question for that part. Thanks

Comment: You can use the panel https://codepen.io/nhembram/pen/XKEJJp